# Camera stops when trying to capture Photo (Android 4.1.1)

Tags: android, camera, spinner

i have an application where the user can take a photo when clicking a button. After click the camera preview opens without any problem. But after taking the photo and clicking "OK" the camera stops and shows a message "camera has stopped". (Error appears when using the App on a Galaxy S3 with 4.1.1)

In the Log it says:

```
04-20 19:24:50.481 1048-1048/ibas.orosol I/dalvikvm: Could not find 

method android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown
04-20 19:24:50.481 1048-1048/ibas.orosol W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18089: Landroid/widget/PopupWindow;.showAsDropDown (Landroid/view/View;III)V
04-20 19:24:50.533 1048-1048/ibas.orosol I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 47.112MB for 640012-byte allocation
04-20 19:24:50.549 1048-1048/ibas.orosol E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.<init>
04-20 19:24:50.549 1048-1048/ibas.orosol W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 2214 (Landroid/widget/ThemedSpinnerAdapter;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter;
```

***Activity***

```
public class BildActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSION = 123; //kann jegliche Zahl sein. Wir benutzens halt später
final private int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 555; //kann jegliche Zahl sein. Wir benutzens halt später

private ImageView mImageView;
private Uri mUri;
private String mCurrentPhotoPath = "";
private Bitmap mBitmap;

Spinner spinner;

Boolean tokenImage;

RequestQueue queue;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bild);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.kopf_app, null));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(R.drawable.kamera);

    tokenImage = false;

    // wenn die Permission NICHT gegeben wurde... und was wir dann machen kommt in diesem Block
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){

            //Hier können wir eintragen, wieso wir eigentlich die Permission brauchen/verlangen
        }else{

            //Permission anfragen
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSION);
        }
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSION);


    //Drop-Down-Menü (Spinner) erstelllen:
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    //Die Werte des Menüs können in den Stringressourcen festgelegt werden und dann hier eingbunden werden (hier die String Rssource "R.array.arten"

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.arten, R.layout.spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); //Hier das DropDown-Design festlegen...eigenes erstellen und hier angeben geht auch
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Change DropDownIcon-Color
    spinner.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    //.getSelectedItem().toString();

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);



}

public void takePicture(View view) throws IOException {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    try{
        File file =  createImageFile();

        mUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplication().getApplicationContext(),
                "ibas.provider", file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    String path = "sdcard/orosol/captured_image.jpg";
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.i("uri-data", "Uri: " + mUri.toString());


        mBitmap = getBitmapFromUri(mImageView, BildActivity.this, mUri);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = 1000;
        mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        tokenImage = true;
    }

}

public void bildAnfrageSenden(View view){

    if(MainActivity.sharedPreferences.getInt("later", -1) == 1){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(BildActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Information")
                .setMessage("Es werden weitere Angaben benötigt, um die Anfrage senden zu können.")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(BildActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("von", "BildActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);

                        dialogInterface.cancel();

                    }
                }).show();
    }else if(!tokenImage){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(BildActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Information")
                .setMessage("Bitte erstellen Sie erst ein Bild.")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                }).show();

    }else if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Bitte wählen")) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(BildActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Information")
                .setMessage("Bitte definieren Sie Ihre Anfrage.")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                }).show();

    } else{

            new AlertDialog.Builder(BildActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Information")
                    .setMessage("Möchten Sie Ihre Anfrage senden?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            anfrageSenden();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Nein", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    }




private void anfrageSenden(){

    final String bitmapString = getBase64StringFromBitmap(mBitmap);

    String url = "LINK";
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("response", response);
                    // response

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(BildActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Information")
                            .setMessage("Ihre Anfrage wurde gesendet.")
                            .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                                }
                            }).show();

                    //TODO: bei Anfrage ohne Daten -> wieder zurück zu Main-Activity
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("test", "1");
            params.put("image", bitmapString);
            params.put("art", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

            params.put("name", MainActivity.sharedPreferences.getString("name", "-1"));
            params.put("tel", (MainActivity.sharedPreferences.getString("telefonnummer", "-1")));
            params.put("kundennummer", MainActivity.sharedPreferences.getString("kundennummer", "-1"));
            params.put("email", MainActivity.sharedPreferences.getString("email", "-1"));

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);

}




private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(ImageView imageView, Context context, Uri uri) {

    if (uri == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = imageView.getHeight();
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = null;
    try {

        parcelFileDescriptor =
                context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();

        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, opts);
        int photoW = opts.outWidth;
        int photoH = opts.outHeight;

        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        opts.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        opts.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, opts);

        if (image.getWidth() > image.getHeight()) {
            Matrix mat = new Matrix();
            int degree = 90;
            mat.postRotate(degree);
            Bitmap imageRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), mat, true);
            return imageRotate;
        } else {
            return image;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("fail", "Failed to load image.", e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
                parcelFileDescriptor.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("error", "Error closing ParcelFile Descriptor");
        }
    }
}

private String getBase64StringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String base64StringOfBitmap = Base64.encodeToString(getBitmapData(bitmap), 1); // die 1 ist ein Flag
    Log.i("base64", base64StringOfBitmap);
    Log.i("length", base64StringOfBitmap.length() + "");
    return base64StringOfBitmap;
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromBase64String(String base64String) {
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(base64String, 1); // die 1 ist ein Flag
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decoded, 0, decoded.length); //Returns the decoded Bitmap, or null if the image could not be decoded.
    return bitmap;
}

private byte[] getBitmapData(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, blob);

    byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
    //System.out.println(blob.toByteArray());


    try {
        blob.close();
        blob = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmapdata; //als byte []
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(int drawableResId) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
            drawableResId);
    return bitmap;
}
```

On my Galaxy s6 it works like a charm.

Comment: There is nothing in the code in your question that has anything to do with a camera.

Comment: Edited. Please take a look

Comment: Presumably, that message is coming from whatever camera app you are using. Does LogCat have any messages from *that* app?

Comment: I am Using Genymotion Emulator for testing. The camera App is the default in in the Emulator. I have a customer who tried with a galaxy s3, same stop of camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked you if LogCat has any messages from the camera app that is crashing. If you find out what those messages are, they may give you some clues.

You will improve compatibility if you call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` to your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`.

However, overall, not every camera app will support a `Uri` with a `content` scheme as the destination for the image. Google's own camera app did not support that until around this time last year. You may be better served using `FileProvider` only on Android 7.0+ devices and using `Uri.fromFile()` for the older devices.

Comment: it could be that failure. How to Change the code to fit both (above 7.0 and below 7.0-devices)?

Comment: @skm: Check `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to see what version of Android you are running on, and choose your `Uri` accordingly. On `Build.VERSION_CODES.N` or higher devices, use the `FileProvider` `Uri`. On older devices, use `Uri.fromFile()`. In both cases, the image should be written to the same place -- what differs is the `Uri` that you are using.